# How to remove the >> indicators from eclipse code view?

Tags: eclipse

[image]

How to remove >>   >>   >>  that signs from eclipse.

Comment: If you are trying to post some code then either copy paste it or post a link to the code. Screen shot isnt good enough. and in this case not viewable either

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to remove, and what would you like to replace them with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disable `Show Whitespace Characters` by clicking on this icon in the toolbar: [image]

Answer (score 2):

Those are called white space characters. You can read more about them [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Programming_Languages). To remove them, uncheck this check box and apply your changes-

Windows->Preferences->General->Editors->Text Editors->Show white space characters